# Mozilla Firefox moz_places last_visit_date is not showing correct time

Tags: sqlite, firefox, datetime, mozilla

Its been more than 3 hours playing with Firefox Moz_places table from places.sqlite file of firefox 3... i am unable to understand why the timing shown through last_visit_date returns me wrong timing difference by less than 3 hours from my current time.

For e.g. if its 3:57 pm it shows 1 PM through last_visit_date..a sample last visit time data is 1379767479983000 which is showing through my query as 2013-09-21 12:44:39 while it has to show 2013-09-21 04:44:39 or 2013-09-21 16:44:39. Through browser history tab it shows correct timing as 04:44:39 pm

When i check Firefox history it shows me correct timing , now i am wondering weather my select statement has problem in conversion or not.

```
select url,title,last_visit_date as raw_visit_date,datetime(last_visit_date/1000000,'unixepoch') as last_visit_date from moz_places
```

Kindly advice what could be the reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to adjust the date. Cannot quite remember if it was (from UTC to) `localtime` or the other way round (from local time) to `utc`.

```
select datetime('1379767479983000'/1000000,'unixepoch','localtime');
select datetime('1379767479983000'/1000000,'unixepoch','utc');
```

See: [Date And Time Functions](http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)